# Error 'undefined' is null or not an object in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, magento

In my magento code 1 file is there.
Name of file - header.phtml

I got error like 'undefined' is null or not an object.

And if i debug that page from IE itself than it will break code from "var hashIndex = frameId.indexOf('#');" from following code.

```
function getFrameId()
{
    var qs = parseQueryString(window.location.href);
    var frameId = qs["frameId"];

    var hashIndex = frameId.indexOf('#');

    if (hashIndex > -1)
    {
        frameId = frameId.substring(0, hashIndex);
    }

    return frameId;
}
```

Comment: In the said line, try to see the value of frameId, I am afraid it is null.

Comment: Seems `frameId` is not beeing assigned a string but instead is `undefined` (probably). What is the value of `qs`? What should it be? What does `parseQueryString` do and what should it return?

Comment: alert(qs); -> return [object object]     alert(frameId); -> return undefined and after that error box is open. alert(hashIndex); not execute at all.

Answer (score 3):

indexOf is not supported in IE. You will need to write your own indexOf function. For example:

```
//Implement indexOf. (IE/mshta doesn't have it)
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, fromIndex) {
    if (fromIndex == null) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    } else if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex = Math.max(0, this.length + fromIndex);
    }
    for (var i = fromIndex, j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (this[i] === obj)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };
```

Comment: nice catch! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

'undefined' is null or not an object means that the java script object that you invoked any method on , is either null or a value that doesn't support that particular method.

in this case`var frameId = qs["frameId"];` i think this returned null, could you see what the qs contains and if there are any value associated with frameid key

Comment: alert(qs); -> return [object object]                      alert(frameId); -> return undefined                                  and after that error box is open. alert(hashIndex); not execute at all.

Comment: correct that means, that qs is an object but , the frameid is not an object in that array, may be you can use any debugger to see what you need, do you have this site hosted somewhere ,so that we may lookup and try to help you over there

Comment: Yeah, just checked, its the same problem there is no element named frameId , but a confusing fact i noticed what , the url that the window had was http://www.cloudcommons.com/#http://www.cloudcommons.com/c/iframe/proxy?p_l_id=10519&p_p_id=48_INSTANCE_sWi2  , that means there is nothing name frameId, and thats the reason why it is not bieng populated

Comment: @dayana could you join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10528/js-undefined-or-null

Comment: In chat from where i can write my message? :(( Can you please give me your yahoo ID if u dont have any problem. bcoz i dont have rights to chat with you...

Comment: You are not authorized to chat, you can message me at akash2004u@gmail.com, if you use any jabber client ,

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 console.debug(qs);
```

in firefox or chrome and inspect that object. Not only will you confirm that you have or haven't the frameId property in the object, but you'll also be able to inspect all the content of that object, and maybe find the information you're looking for in a different object key.